# chinese charactors eat other charactor when lua loadstring

Tags: python, character-encoding, lua, escaping, double-quotes

when i **load data in lua by loadstring**, some magic chinese charactors fail.

```
RawData = '{a="a朶b"}'
Data = loadstring("return " .. RawData)()
```

that's because:

- "朶" 's ascii char(gbk encoding) is 0x96 0x5c
- 0x5c is '\', which will escape everything afterwards.
- so, **'{a="a朶b"}'** becomes   **'{a="a\150\b"}'** ,  \b is the wrong answer

then, i will never get the right output "a朶b" ,  "b" is eaten by "朶" ....

**the same quote problem happens in python:**

```
exec("""print '''a朶b''' """)
```

---

**there are some ways to handle this in python:**

- clearly define the encoding in file  -*- coding:gbk -*-
- use utf-8 for string/file encoding

but lua only support standard C, any quote or escaping ideas?

---

by the way, this works:

```
RawData = [=[ {a=[[a朶b]]} ]=]
return  loadstring("return " .. RawData)() .a
```

but i have to change the original RawData, that's unacceptable.

**question 2:**

how to keep string in lua not escaped?  (python does this job so good)

```
s  = "a朶b"
s1 = string.format("%q", s)    -- s escaped
return s                       -- s escaped
print(s)                       -- s escaped
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was discussed on the [Lua mailing list](http://lua-list.2524044.n2.nabble.com/Future-plans-for-Lua-and-Unicode-td7581149.html), Lua handles UTF-8 in string literals just fine. If you can save the file in UTF-8, you will have no problems with Lua. If you need to later use the GBK encoding (like saving it in a file or serving a webpage in the encoding), you can use the [lua-iconv](http://luaforge.net/projects/lua-iconv/) library to convert from UTF-8 literals to GBK:

```
local iconv = require "iconv"
local toGbk = iconv.new("GBK", "UTF-8")
function U2G(s) return toGbk:iconv(s) end

-- assuming the while file is saved in UTF-8, this will output the string in GBK
print(U2G "a朶b")
```

The other thing you can do is convert from GBK to UTF-8 before using `loadstring`. Then do not forget to convert back from UTF-8 when presenting the results to the user.

Comment: this seems to be the best solution. but need an external lib, and converting for every bit.

Answer (score 0):

what about inserting a '\' before 0x5c?

Comment: 朶 is a 2-byte charactor, nothing can be insert between that 2 byte.  Even can, i should not modify Origin RawData.

Comment: i meant replace '\' with '\\'

Comment: any action touch the '\' will break that 2-byte charactor away.

Comment: what if your some other RawData contains "\b"? what will you do?

Comment: Since Lua doesn't do any character encoding/decoding at all, you will need to do this (and also escape other tricky bytes like `"`.) When you print out the string, the escapes will be removed, and you'll end up with the original 2-byte character. This destroys the ability to look at the character in the original source, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your RawData is just improperly encoded and I don't see it worth adding some "heuristic" that would guess which of those are part of multibyte or standalone. You should change its serializer (or inform their developers) that they should escape symbols Lua treat as special in their strings before placing them into serialization. In this particular case all `\` must be converted to `\\` before string is added to serialization.

If your data source is written in some common language it might be worth to check out if there's ready Lua serialization library available.

Comment: i add a new question: in lua how to keep string not escaped?